# Gitlab shared runner set concurrence for each project

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

A shared runner is used by dozens of our project. I set `concurrent = 5` in config.toml, so my runner can do 5 job concurrently for all project.

For example, the following scenario：3 job for A project, 2 job for B project, 0 job for C project which causes C project should wait for at least 1 job of A or B project being finished until it starts first job.

I want to set like "all project `concurrent = 5`" and "each project `concurrent = 2`". Is there any way to deal with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an open issue for your problem [here](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/15325).

One of the options [proposed by users](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/15325#note_214799670) is to register your worker with multiple runners, use `concurrent` in global runner configuration and `limit` parameter per runner. Then you can set tag in each project yaml to execute on runner which is limited to 2 parallel jobs.

[Runners](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/configuration/advanced-configuration.html#the-runners-section) config would look like():

```
concurrent = 5
[[runners]]
  limit = 2
  name = "project-a-runner"
  ...

[[runners]]
  limit = 2
  name = "project-b-runner"
  ...
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, All of our projects use the same runner tag.  It means I should register 2 runner with the same tag?

Comment: If we consider example you described in your question, then it should be: `concurrent = 5` + 3 runners with `limit = 2` and each runner for different project. This way you distribute equally 2 parallel jobs to each project but limit them globally to 5. So last project to get the runner will have only 1 parallel job.